# PHFetchOptions predicate with NSDate compare

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nspredicate, phasset

Hello I had been working with `Photos.framework` but now I am stuck with predicate comparison of `PHFetchOptions` class in documents I see that we can use `startDate` to use in predicate. So my code is this

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray * moments;
}



@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    moments = [NSMutableArray array];

    if([PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus] == PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {
        [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {
            [self loadCollections];
        }];
    }else
    {
        [self loadCollections];
    }

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self loadCollections];
}


- (NSDate*)dateAddingDays:(NSInteger)days ToDate:(NSDate*)argDate
{
    NSCalendar * gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSString * dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:argDate];
    NSDate * toWorkDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setDay:days];
    NSDate *date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:toWorkDate  options:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]);
    return date;
}

- (void)loadCollections
{
    PHFetchOptions * options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc]init];

    options.predicate = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate > CAST(%d,\"NSDate\")",[self dateAddingDays2:-1 ToDate:[NSDate date]].timeIntervalSince1970];
    PHFetchResult * result = [PHAssetCollection fetchMomentsWithOptions:options];

    if(result != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"%i",result.count);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.count; i++) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[result objectAtIndex:i]);
            [moments addObject:[result objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }

}
```

So my problem is this, I need fetch fotos from one day ago, I can make this work!! any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate > %@", [self dateByAddingsDays:-1 ToDate:[NSDate date]]]`? But dateAddingDays:ToDate:` is weird. You shouldn't do it like this. Not with a `NSDateFormatter` anyways (and  `ToDate:` should be `toDate:` (lowercase start)

Comment: Thanks this works great! y also change my [self dateByAddingsDays:-1 ToDate:[NSDate date]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer, basically I replaced

```
- (NSDate*)dateAddingDays:(NSInteger)days ToDate:(NSDate*)argDate
{
    NSCalendar * gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSString * dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:argDate];
    NSDate * toWorkDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setDay:days];
    NSDate *date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:toWorkDate  options:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]);
    return date;
}
```

by

```
- (NSDate*)yesterday
{
    NSCalendar * gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    return [gregorian startOfDayForDate:[gregorian dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:-1 toDate:[NSDate date] options:NSCalendarWrapComponents]];
}
```

and also replace this

```
options.predicate = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate > CAST(%d,\"NSDate\")",[self dateAddingDays2:-1 ToDate:[NSDate date]].timeIntervalSince1970];
```

by this

```
options.predicate = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startDate > %@)",[self yesterday]];
```

and now is working!!! thanks to @Larme